# Can not connect to Remote SVN repositories

Tags: svn

I am unable to connect to any remote repository to check out the code. I get the following error consistently.

```
svn: E175002: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk'
svn: E175002: OPTIONS of 'http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk': Could not resolve hostname `svn.apache.org'
: This is usually a temporary error during hostname resolution and means that the local server did not receive a response from an authoritative server. (http://svn.apache.org)
```

The command that I used is

```
svn co http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk subversion
```

I can access the repository using a browser without any issues.

It seems to be an issue with the settings here, as I can access the locally hosted(on my computer, as well as on the corporate network) SVN repositories seamlessly.

Edit:
Once I figured out that SVN does not use the proxy settings of the host machine, I could quickly edit my **servers** file to fix the issue.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me towards the resolution.

Comment: Check `http-proxy-host` and related config in SVNBook http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.confarea.html#svn.advanced.confarea.opts.config

Answer (score 0):

Try pinging the svn server from terminal. If it's not able to resolve the name you might have to check your DNS server config.

Comment: I am behind a proxy and can not ping even Google!

Comment: Then obviously that's the problem.

Comment: But are you trying to access the svn repository from the same machine that you're browsing from? Or perhaps you are on a vnc session on another server that might have access restrictions. Just checking all possibilities.

Comment: @VaibhavGarg - Then you should be asking how to configure the subversion client to use a proxy.

Comment: Well, that assumes that I know that it's a proxy issue @ÁlvaroG.Vicario which I didn't.

Comment: I was not scolding you, just letting you know what the issue is :)

Answer (score 0):

If the browser is able to access it but not the SVN client, perhaps it's some kind of caching or DNS issue. I would suggest firstly trying to flush the DNS cache with one of the methods described [here](http://www.techiecorner.com/35/how-to-flush-dns-cache-in-linux-windows-mac/) (you don't mention which platform this is on). If that doesn't work then reboot and try again.  If you still have the problem then try switching to another account on the machine and check out from there, just to see if it's a problem with the machine or with your account. If it's fine on the other account then maybe it's your SVN client settings that may be messed up, so try taking a copy of the `~/.subversion` folder (or `%APPDATA%\.subversion` on Windows) then deleting it and try again.